# How to control spooling and echo in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper, spool

I need to write a deployment script which will execute each sql script and log their buffer as per spooling path defined.

```
    Deployment.sql
set echo on;

SPOOL C:\Temp\Log\scriptLog\MasterScript.log
/*  Start executing script srcipt 1*/
 @C:\scr\script1.sql;
/*  End executing script srcipt 1*/ 


 SPOOL C:\Temp\Log\scriptLog\MasterScript.log append;

/*  Start executing script srcipt 2*/
 @C:\scr\script2.sql
 /* End executing script srcipt 2*/

 SET echo OFF
SPOOL OFF
```

Above deployment script will execute script1 and script2. I want that spooling of script1 and script2 should not append on spooling of deployment script . And spooling of deployment script should only contains below mentioned (means what I logged in deployment script)

```
  /*    Start executing script srcipt 2*/
     @C:\scr\script2.sql
     /* End executing script srcipt 2*/
```

I tried all possible solution used append of spooling  , did googling a lot but did not get appropriate solution. Kindly suggest

```
Script1.sql
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Test_script.sql
-- This is Test script one
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 SET echo ON
SPOOL C:\Temp\Log\scriptLog\Script1.log

begin
/* This is inside spool of script 1 */

dbms_output.put_line('FIrst Script');
end;
/
spool off;
set echo off;


script2.sql
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Test_script.sql
-- This is Test script two
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET echo ON
SPOOL C:\Temp\Log\scriptLog\Script2.log

begin
/* This is inside spool of script 2 */

dbms_output.put_line('SECOND Script');
end;
/
Spool off;
set echo off;
```

My requirement is no single line of script1 and script2 spooling should append in deployment script , and as mentioned spooling of script1 and script2 logged seperately as provided

Comment: have you tried setting `SET LINESIZE` and `SET TRIMSPOOL` with the required values?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear what you want to see in each log file, but I think this is close.

deployment.sql:

```
spool C:\Temp\Log\scriptLog\MasterScript.log
/* Start executing script 1 */
@C:\scr\script1.sql
spool C:\Temp\Log\scriptLog\MasterScript.log append
/* End executing script 1 */

/* Start executing script 2 */
@C:\scr\script2.sql
spool C:\Temp\Log\scriptLog\MasterScript.log append
/* End executing script 2 */

spool off
```

script1.sql:

```
spool off
set echo off

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Test_script.sql
-- This is Test script one
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

set echo on
spool C:\Temp\Log\scriptLog\Script1.log

begin
/* This is inside spool of script 1 */

dbms_output.put_line('FIRST Script');
end;
/

spool off
set echo off
```

and script2.sql is the same structure:

```
spool off
set echo off

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Test_script.sql
-- This is Test script two
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

set echo on
spool C:\Temp\Log\scriptLog\Script2.log

begin
/* This is inside spool of script 2 */

dbms_output.put_line('SECOND Script');
end;
/

spool off
set echo off
```

When run from SQL*Plus that produces MasterScript.log:

```
SQL> /* Start executing script 1 */
SQL> @C:\scr\script1.sql
SQL> /* End executing script 1 */
SQL>
SQL> /* Start executing script 2 */
SQL> @C:\scr\script2.sql
SQL> /* End executing script 2 */
SQL>
SQL> spool off
```

Script1.log:

```
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2  /* This is inside spool of script 1 */
  3
  4  dbms_output.put_line('FIRST Script');
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> spool off
```

and Script2.log

```
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2  /* This is inside spool of script 2 */
  3
  4  dbms_output.put_line('SECOND Script');
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> spool off
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for replaying , but when I tried above mentioned with my actual script where Termout and feedback  on , the spooling of deployment script went inside script1, not working for me

Comment: @Arun - this has termout and feedback left on. No idea what you're doing differently though, sorry.

Comment: My bad , I should have added Termout and feedbak on with my question , I will edit the question , Might be you can point me in right direction . Thank a ton for help

Comment: @Arun - but termout and feedback are on by default, and they were on for the demo I did and the output I put in the answer. Neither will affect spooling, or what goes in each output file. The *terminal* will see the output from all three scripts, but the spool files won't. If you're seeing output in the wrong file then you aren't doing spool off and restarting spool in all the same places - but I can't guess what you've done differently.